# How to make a Text in Button to Blink(Flashing) in ADF(Jdev)

Tags: button, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, dynamic-data-display

I need help to make my Text in button or Alteast a Text to Blink(Flashing).

Example, Alerts used to should blink

Comment: Welcome to the site. That's a long time I've not seen a blinking caption, it may not be very well received by users. Changing the color is in most cases a less disturbing alternative.

Comment: But thats wat our Requirement. Moreover Alerts should be Blinking, thats why im looking for it.

Comment: FYI, blinking at some frequencies may be a problem for certain persons: [Section 508 of the Rehabilitation Act  1194.21(k)](http://accessibility.gtri.gatech.edu/assistant/acc_info/std_1194_21k_main.php), Oracle ADF [complies](http://www.oracleimg.com/us/corporate/accessibility/templates/t2-2786.html) with this section itself.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the others that blinking component is a bad UI.
That being said, you can use an af:poll component to have a short timer and when it expires you can change the color of the text or background of a component and then restart the poll.
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/using_the_afpoll_to_refresh_pa